# How to get playlistid for YTPlayerView

Tags: ios, google-api, youtube-api, ytplayerview

I am loading a video in YTPlayerView, but for loading playlist in YTPlayerView we need playlistId. I don't see this in the response

```
playerVars = @{
               @"autoplay" : @1
               ,@"rel" : @0
               ,@"playsinline" : @1
               ,@"showinfo" : @0
               ,@"modestbranding" : @1
               ,@"listType":@"playlist"
               ,@"autohide":@1
               };

 [[YTPlayerInstance instance] loadWithVideoId:@"jrmilwr1y6w" playerVars:playerVars];
```

This is OK

```
[[YTPlayerInstance instance] loadWithPlaylistId:playListId playerVars:playerVars];
```

Where is this playListId in response. How can I get this playListId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a playlist id with the YouTube Data API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/ 

From what I understand in your example you've hardcoded the video's id. Obviously you can do the same with a playlist's id.

The best way to get IDs (and data in general) from YouTube is through the YouTube Data API.

As you can see in this example https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlists.list?part=snippet&channelId=UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw&maxResults=50&fields=items&_h=2&

i'm asking for all the playlist of a particular channel. You can find each playlist id at the field "id". For example: "id": "PLYH8WvNV1YEmuUM8tmQ2BJx3Uq9QzSivx"